# Ideals generated by roots of polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, algebraic-number-theory, ideals

Let $\alpha$ be a root of $x^3-2x+6$. Let $K=\mathbb{Q}[\alpha]$ and let denote by $\mathscr{O}_K$ the number ring of $K$. Now consider the ideal generated by $(4,\alpha^2,2\alpha,\alpha -3)$ in $\mathscr{O}_K$. I want to prove that this ideal is actually the entire ring $\mathscr{O}_K$. Do i need to know who $\alpha$ is to do this? Is there any theorem which could help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint/steps for one route that caught my eye. There may be a shorter one out there. Call that ideal $I$. Observe that $\alpha \in {\cal O}_K$.

1. Show that $\alpha+1\in I$.
2. Show that $\alpha^2-1\in I$.
3. Show that $1\in I$.

Remark: this is my second suggestion - the first suggestion had 5 steps.

Answer (score 4):

In fact, already $I=(4,\alpha-3)$ is equal to $O_K$. To see it, let's compute the norms (in $K/\mathbb Q$) of $4$ and of $\alpha-3$: $N(4)=4^3$ and $N(\alpha-3)=(\alpha-3)(\beta-3)(\gamma-3)=-(3^3-2\times3+6)=-27$, where $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ are the roots of $x^3-2x+6$. But the norm $|O_K/I|$ of $I$ divides the norms of all its elements, so it is $1$, i.e. $I=O_K$.